# which is strong ubuntu dist or windows?

Tags: networking, security, network-monitoring

Gentlemen, i am using windows in my company. I want to secure my system or to secure my company systems. should my company use linux(ubuntu) to become more secure than windows 8 ?
**what also the precautions to be implemented to secure the company network ?** I thought first thing my company should do is to use ubuntu which is completely different from windows.
 **So I asked this question here** and please some help.

Comment: Take a look at http://techluminati.com/operating-systems/linux-vs-windows/

Answer (score 4):

> Should my company use linux(ubuntu) to become more secure than windows 8 ?

The choice of operating system is not what makes your company more secure. I can install Ubuntu and set UFW up so even a 5 year old Chinese girl from Xia He (*) can access your server and issue an `rm` command. And it is also possible to hammer down Windows so not even an expert can break in to it.

Yes, Linux/Ubuntu comes with more sane defaults but that is also due to Linux being multi-user from the get go and Windows starting as a single user machine. Linux/Ubuntu needs to hide things on the system itself from users so the evil outside should not be able to do more.

*It is the administrator of those systems that makes your systems secure*.

Linux/Ubuntu has a better track record than Windows when it comes to viruses: they are nearly non existent and the viruses that do exist have not left the laboratory yet. So that might be an option.

> What also the precautions to be implemented to secure the company network ?

When someone from then outside connects to your inner system make sure to do this over a secure line (think https, ssl for websites you host, vpn for ssh).

We have a mixed network. Our routers block/grant traffic, most here use Windows PCs for daily usage. We employees are allowed to use the operating system we prefer as long as we can do what is needed to be done. And our servers and our clients servers are all Ubuntu, some CentOS and some are SCO Open Server. And all our own servers also use UFW as an extra barrier.

(*) monastery in eastern China.

Comment: you mean we can't do any thing only the desingner of the system who could make it more secure?

Comment: The employees at your company and you are what make a system secure. And 1 of them will be an admin so he is the preferred one to secure systems but no system can prevent you from someone emailing a password to someone that then "breaks" into your system. Social engineering will kill any form of security.